# Memory of Reference Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, memory

JavaScript stores Reference Values in Heap memory and thus variables stores to a pointer/address. So, if we change original variable, it changes the assigned one as well:

```
var cols = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
var newCols = cols

cols.push('orange')

console.log(cols) 
// returns ["red", "blue", "green", "orange"]
console.log(newCols)
// returns ["red", "blue", "green", "orange"]
```

However, when I experimenting for reference types, I find out that, when I am using indexing for assignment and push method they act in not same logic which I did not expect:

```
var cols = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
var newCols=cols[1]
cols[1] = "pink"
console.log(cols)
// returns > ["red", "pink", "green"]
console.log(newCols)
// returns > "blue"  WHY?
```

But:

```
var cols = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
var newCols=cols
newCols[3] = 'orange'
cols.push('yellow')

console.log(cols)
// returns > ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "yellow"]
console.log(newCols)
// returns > ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "yellow"] WHY?
```

So, what is the logic ('the idea under the hood') here that, in one sample, it affects original, but in another it does not?

Comment: newCols in the second code is assigned the value - it does not "point" to a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
var newCols=cols[1]
```

you essentially take the reference to the value that `cols[1]` currently holds, and have `newCols` point to it too. For example, say `cols[1]`, currently the `'blue'` string, is at memory location #5432. Then doing `newCols=cols[1]` has `newCols` also point to #5432.

The array that `cols` is is also an array of references to memory locations. So `['red', 'blue', 'green']` could be thought of as `[#987, #5432, #123]`. Reassigning one of the indicies puts a new reference at that spot. After `cols[1] = "pink"`, you can think of `cols` as now containing `[#987, #333, #123]`.

The original item at `#5432` - `'pink'` - is not affected. `newCols`, which points to #5432, still points to `'pink'`.

When you do

```
var newCols=cols
```

the *whole array container* is pointed to from two variables. Eg, both `cols` and `newCols` point to #55555. So mutating one will result in the other appearing to change as well.

(The "memory location" is a useful *visualization*, but it's not necessarily how it isn't how things work under the hood - this is just an easy way of thinking about it)

Comment: it is much more cleaner for now, but its hard to grasp the idea in crystal clear. Is there any visual source that can explain graphical way exactly this issue? 
Thank you for your answer by the way.

Comment: I guess one could take the above information and make a video of it instead or something, or maybe one already exists, but I'm not going to make one - if anything isn't clear, just ask